# cambiar formato entre fechas leyendo csv

Tags: python, api, date, datetime

Estoy intentando capturar correctamente las fechas de una lectura de archivo csv, logro poder recorrer las filas correctamente, mi problema reside en la logica. El formato de fechas dentro de este csv puede ser cualquiera.
Necesito dejar todas las fechas en el formato '%Y-%m-%d'. Trato te ocupar strptime y luego convertirlo a date pero me salta un error de formato.

Ejemplo:

```
Fechas ----> transformacion

2020/06/23 06:00    
--->   2020-06-23
23/04/2020 05:00    
--->   2020-04-23
11/4/2020  10:00    
--->   2020-04-11
2022/1/24  11:00    
--->   2022-01-04
```

Codigo:

```
  ## BUSCO FECHA EN CSV ##
  for row in csvfile:
      fecha_csv = row[7]      
      fecha_csv = datetime.strptime(fecha_csv, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      fecha_csv = fecha_csv.date()
```

Comment: strptime no parsea en cualquier formato, solo en el que especifiques. Para lograr lo qeu buscas tendrás que usar librerías de terceros como [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) o crear tu propia librería.

Comment: @DanteS. No necesito parsear, necesito que de una fecha cualquiera, transformarla y que siempre quede con formato %Y-%m-%d

Comment: Para eso primero necesitas obtener la fecha. Luego darle el nuevo formato. Así que de cierto modo necesitas parsear (aunque sea implicitamente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si lo haces con `pandas` es muy fácil

Primero importamos el archivo y creamos un `dataframe` (Cree un archivo sencillo llamado sample.csv):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve

```
    fecha
0   2020/06/23 06:00
1   23/04/2020 05:00
2   11/4/2020 10:00
3   2022/1/24 11:00
```

Del lado izquierdo vemos los índices (Si no elegiste alguna columna como tu índice entonces se generan números de 0 a N) y del lado derecho verás tus columnas con los nombres mostrados en el CSV, si tu CSV no tiene la primera fila con el nombre de las columnas entonces tus columnas también recibirán como "nombre" números enteros de 0 a N

Luego, lo único que tenemos que hacer es seleccionar la columna que tengan las fechas, las convertimos al formato deseado y la asignamos a cualquier columna (Puede ser la columna original, como en el ejemplo siguiente)

```
df['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    fecha
0   2020-06-23
1   2020-04-23
2   2020-11-04
3   2022-01-24
```

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta que fechas con números menores a 12 para mes y día es muy dificil de "adivinar" el formato original que tienen, por ejemplo, si la fecha fuera 3 de abril del 2022, entonces podría verse así 03/04/2022 (Formato día, mes, año) o podría verse así 04/03/2022 (Formato mes, día, año) entre otras combinaciones, por lo que en esos casos tal vez las fechas resultantes estarían mal

El método utilizado [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) tiene varios argumentos que podrían ayudarte, te recomiendo que leas un poco de la documentación para que la respuesta sea más clara.